# What development process is supposed to be used for Fujifilm motion picture stock?

Tags: film, developing, fujifilm

What process should be used to develop Fujifilm motion picture stock such as Eterna 400T or F-64D? Is it ECN-2 like the Kodak Vision3 films, C-41 with a remjet removal step or something else entirely? To my surprise I couldn't find any information regarding the official specifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Fuji's marketing sheet](https://www.fujifilm.com/products/motion_picture/pdf/eterna400.pdf) states, the film is processed in ECN-2.

If it is not often mentioned, it is probably because it is just as obvious, that colour negative cinema film is processed in ECN-2, as it is that still film is processed in C-41.

Comment: I had looked straight over that. I wasn't sure either that ECN-2 was considered the de facto standard for motion picture film like C-41 is for colour negative still film.